# Adding millions of nodes to neo4j spatial layer using cypher and apoc

Tags: neo4j, cypher, neo4j-spatial, neo4j-apoc

I have a data set of 3.8million nodes and I'm trying to load all of these into Neo4j spatial. The nodes are going into a simple point layer, so have the required latitude and longitude fields. I've tried:

```
MATCH (d:pointnode) 
WITH collect(d) as pn 
CALL spatial.addNodes("point_geom", pn) yield count return count
```

But this just keeps spinning without anything happening. I've also tried (I've been running the next query all on one line, but I've just split it up for ease of reading):

```
CALL apoc.periodic.iterate("MATCH (d:pointnode) 
WITH collect(d) AS pnodes return pnodes",
"CALL spatial.addNodes('point_geom', pnodes) YIELD count return count", 
{batchSize:10000, parallel:false, listIterate:true})
```

But again a lot of spinning and the occasional JAVA heap error.

The final approach I tried was to use FME with the HTTP caller, this works but is exceptionally slow so doesn't scale well for millions of nodes.

Any advice or suggestions would be much appreciated. Would apoc.periodic.commit or apoc.periodic.rock_n_roll be a better choice than periodic iterate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a bit of trial and error periodic commit has led to a relatively quick solution (still going to take 2-3 hours)

```
call apoc.periodic.commit("match (n:pointnode) 
where not (n)-[:RTREE_REFERENCE]-() with n limit {limit} 
WITH collect(n) AS pnodes 
CALL spatial.addNodes('point_geom', pnodes) YIELD count return count",
{limit:1000})
```

May be quicker with larger batch sizes

EDIT with a batch size of 5000 it takes 45 minutes

Comment: what does {limit:1000} do ??

Comment: limits the size of the batch, so 1000 nodes are added to the spatial layer on each commit

Comment: i have same issue as you, however your solution dosen't work with me, this is my [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50988626/adding-5834580-of-node-to-spatial-layer)

Answer (score 2):

You have 3 800 000 nodes, you collect them in **one** list ... and then you do **one** call to have that list added to the layer ... that is going to take a while and eat loads of memory. **apoc.periodic.iterate** makes absolutely no difference because you only do **one** call to **spatial.addNodes** ...

It may take a while, but why not add them node by node ?

```
CALL apoc.periodic.iterate(
  "MATCH (d:pointnode) RETURN d",
  "CALL spatial.addNode('point_geom', d) YIELD node RETURN node"
  {batchSize:10000, parallel:false, listIterate:true})
```

Hope this helps (or at least explains why you are having issues).

Regards,
Tom

Comment: Thank you, it does work yes but as you said it's very slow. Would I be right in thinking apocalypse.periodic.commit does not read the all of the nodes at once? So if I can get the syntax right, it will read the first 10,000 nodes, Add them on to the spatial layer. Then move on, therefore needing less memory?

Comment: Yes, but it would require you to first mark the nodes that need processing and then remove that mark of the batch of nodes that you have processed. That's of course going to require extra processing (read: time), but it will reduce memory use. The marking of 3800000 nodes itself will however also take time and memory, so if my original solution is feasible for you (memory wise ... and you can still increase the batchSize somewhat) you may want to stick with that.

Comment: Thanks for you advice Tom, the answer to lies within periodic commit, I'll post the solution as an answer.