# Adding 5834580 of node to Spatial Layer

Tags: neo4j, cypher, neo4j-apoc, neo4j-spatial

I am trying to create an *R-TREE* of **5834580** of nodes.
I found in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45904154/adding-millions-of-nodes-to-neo4j-spatial-layer-using-cypher-and-apoc) a similair problem and i tried it's solution, so this is my code :

```
call apoc.periodic.commit("MATCH (pl:pickup_location) WITH collect(pl) AS pickup CALL spatial.addNodes('nyc',pickup) YIELD count RETURN count",{limit:1000})
```

however, since yesterday the computer didn't finish loading the result.
today, i tried the second answer with iterate :

```
CALL apoc.periodic.iterate(
"MATCH (pl:pickup_location) RETURN pl",
"CALL spatial.addNode('nyc', pl) YIELD node RETURN node",
{batchSize:10000, parallel:false, listIterate:true})
```

and i get this error :

```
Neo.ClientError.Procedure.ProcedureCallFailed: Failed to invoke procedure `apoc.periodic.iterate`: Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
```

what is wrong ? what should i do ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem with the `apoc.periodic.commit` is that your query will always return the same nodes with your `MATCH (pl:pickup_location)`. There is no condition to find only nodes that are not in the spatial layout.

I don't remember the model of the spatial plugin, but from what I remember, on your `pickup_location` nodes, you should have a specific relation to the R-Tree.

So you should transform your auery to something like that :

```
CALL apoc.periodic.commit("
  MATCH (pl:pickup_location)
  WHERE NOT (p1)-[:LINKS->(:spatialNode) // Change this according to the spatial model
  WITH p1 AS node LIMIT $limit
  WITH collect(node) AS pickup 
    CALL spatial.addNodes('nyc',pickup) YIELD count 
    RETURN count",
  {limit:1000}
)
```

For the problem on the `apoc.periodic.iterate` is just a memory problem, you don't have enought RAM to execute transactions.

You have two solutions :

- give more RAM to Neo4j by increasing the heap size of Neo4j (see the `neo4j.conf` file)
- decrease the size of the batch, `10000` is a little big, change it to `1000`

Comment: I don't see usage of `limit` within the query for `commit()`. Unlike `apoc.periodic.iterate()`, you must explicitly add the usage of `limit`. With this query in particular the location of the `limit` is important, since you're collecting down to 1 row, so for this to be effective you need to have `WITH pl LIMIT {limit}` before the WITH clause that performs the collect().

Comment: I have updated my response :) Thanks the point me this missing part

Answer (score 1):

As I don't have a rep of 50 I can't comment but logisima is spot on, just to add to their answer... the "where not" clause should be:

```
where not (p1)-[:RTREE_REFERENCE]-()
```

RTREE_REFERENCE being the relationship created when adding a node to the spatial layer.